# Create an array only knowing max and min values

Tags: php, arrays

Coding in PHP, I currently have an array of 100 values, which looks like this:

```
$cmassarray = array(630.00,629.70,629.40,629.10,628.80,628.50,628.20,627.90,627.60,627.30,627.00,
                626.70,626.40,626.10,625.80,625.50,625.20,624.90,624.60,624.30,624.00,623.70,
                623.40,623.10,622.80,622.50,622.20,621.90,621.60,621.30,621.00,620.70,620.40,
                620.10,619.80,619.50,619.20,618.90,618.60,618.30,618.00,617.70,617.40,617.10,
                616.80,616.50,616.20,615.90,615.60,615.30,615.00,614.70,614.40,614.10,613.80,
                613.50,613.20,612.90,612.60,612.30,612.00,611.70,611.40,611.10,610.80,610.50,
                610.20,609.90,609.60,609.30,609.00,608.70,608.40,608.10,607.80,607.50,607.20,
                606.90,606.60,606.30,606.00,605.70,605.40,605.10,604.80,604.50,604.20,603.90,
                603.60,603.30,603.00,602.70,602.40,602.10,601.80,601.50,601.20,600.90,600.60,
                600.30,600.00);
```

All of the steps are the same length, and I may need to change them (and/or the max/min values) at a future stage, so I would like to find a way to avoid having to re-calculate them manually and type them each time.

If I know the maximum value is 630.00 and the minimum value is 600.00, and that I have 100 steps, would it be possible to create an array specifying that each value is an increment on this equation?

```
x (array value) = 600+((Max-Min)/100)*y)
```

where y is the incremental step in the scale.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using loops and all that would be `range`

```
$start=630;
$stop=600;
$steps=100;
$cmassarray=range( $start, $stop, ( ( $start-$stop ) / $steps ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the `range` function, which takes an optional third argument for step. This argument you can easily derive from your maximum, minimum and amount of steps. Here's an example:

```
$max = 630;
$min = 600;
$steps = 100;
$step = ($max - $min) / $steps;
$your_result = range( $max, $min, $step );
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this code:

```
$max = 630;
$min = 600;
$steps = 100;
$step = ($max - $min) / $steps;
$ar = [];
for ($i = $max; $i >= $min; $i -= $step) {
    $ar[] = $i;
}
```

Comment: Downvoting for the use of a for-loop instead of the use of php's built in `range` function.